# How to integrate the Jquery Validate Plugin with recaptcha?

Tags: php, jquery, recaptcha

Its kind of a boring, when you validate the entire form using Jquery Validate plugin in a quick way, but when it is about the recaptcha, you have to check it on the server.

Can i use jquery validate plugin to check the recaptcha and show the messages, like it usually does for other fields?

Although, I dont know how to build it, may be a validate rule like `required` can be created for recaptcha, which can post the value to a page and get the response.

Comment: This only makes sense, if you do the check on the server too, because otherwise a user simply has to disabled/modify your JavaScript to circumvent your CAPTCHA.

Comment: That can be acceptable, to check it again the server too, but my main motive, lets stop the submission, if it is incorrect on the form first.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435241/php-question-about-using-recaptcha-with-jquery check this out

Answer (score 2):

Guess `remote` is used for recaptcha validate

check it on [here](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/captcha/)

perhaps you should have in your validation

```
 remote : 'someurl.php?someparams'
```

Complete code something like this

```
    rules:{
            username: {required: true},
            password: {required: true},
            email: {required: true, email: true},
            recaptcha: {required: true, remote: "someurl.php"},
            fullname: {required: true}},
    messages: {
            username: "Category name is required",
            password: "Password is required",
            fullname: "Full Name is required",
            recaptcha: {required: "captcha is required", remote: "Invalid captcha"},
            email: "Valid email is required"
        },
```

On your remote url

```
<?php

echo "true";

//or 

echo "false";
```

Comment: What should the someurl.php should return to be considered false. A normal `false` or `0` or `something else`

Comment: @mrN well i guess it's `true` or `false`. just let me try i guess string.

Comment: @mrN it's string. and if your are trying on cross-domain url, then also it will not work.

Comment: It requires, `recaptcha_challege_field` parameter also, how to send this, when you are validate `recaptcha_response_field`

Comment: @mrN could you add your code ultill now??? but i guess it's `remote: "someurl.php?recaptcha_response_field="+somevarstored`

Comment: I dont think echo "true" is working. I tried to just send echo "true", straight to simulate a valid case, didn't show any reaction

Answer (score 0):

No. The reCAPTCHA validation is done Google's servers and involves sending a private key (i.e. something that should never be placed in a publicly accessible location like JavaScript).

Comment: I understand that, but may be a validate rule like `required` can be created for recaptcha, which can post the value to a page and get the response.